# Please roll back this bad edit

Tags: support

I stumbled upon a really bad edit to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4265399/4792869), could somebody having the privilege please roll back to the first revision?

Comment: I think this edit unnecessarily narrows down the question and doesn't significantly improve it, so I rolled it back.

Comment: I don't even know how that edit makes sense. It's barely proper english

Comment: As a side-note, consider chat next time. [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is a good one to ask for this help.

Comment: Yikes.  Maybe the reviewers who approved it need to take some time off from reviewing...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That edit was indeed not very good. Unfortunately, [it was approved by reviewers in the suggested edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9632505) on the 15th September 2015 3-2 (3 for, 2 against).

I have for now taken the liberty of rolling it back.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet At least 2 voted against. That's better than some cases.

Answer (score 4):

For next time, note this.

You can rollback an edit yourself. As you are < 2k, it needs to be approved by users with > 2k. It mostly will get approved unless it is a bad edit. In rare cases, when reviewers are sleeping, and your edit gets rejected, you can ask for help in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or post a meta post like this time.

If this is happening time to time, I would suggest to ask for help in SOCVR instead of posting a meta question each time. But if you like, you can ask for advice on meta, why so many of your edits which seem correct are being rejected.

Comment: Can a <2K user suggest an actual roll back of an edit (on someone else's post), or just suggest an edit which effectively undoes the prior edit?