# Roll back latest edit of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7122609?

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

The [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7122609/revisions) of
[How do I reference a JavaScript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7122609) shows how the editor replaced "javascript"
with "jQuery" in the title and also removed the tag [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and
added the tag [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

To me all these changes are blatantly ***wrong***.
Please advise on how to settle this dispute.
In my opinion the edit in question should simply be **rolled back**.

Similar request as of 2016: [Please roll back this bad edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319668).

Comment: @oguzismail it is.. the question seems to be regarding the code `style.text-align`

Comment: "*jQuery is not JavaScript*" what?

Comment: The state has been rolled back to revision 2.

Comment: It does seem wrong, but doesn't the `$` make it somewhat jQueryish?

Comment: @PeterMortensen jQuery is _used_ in the snippet but is not relevant to OP's problem

Comment: @PeterMortensen no. Whether or not jQuery is involved is entirely unrelated. OP wants to access a property off an object and *expects* the property to have a dash in it. However, that's not syntactically valid in JS. The fact that jQuery is involved doesn't really change that. If anything the convention of a `two-words` CSS property becoming `twoWords` JavaScript property pre-dates jQuery.

Comment: If it doesn't have anything to do with jQuery, perhaps it'd be better if someone changed `$(this)` to something else. Assuming it causes confusion of course, I don't know either language

Comment: @oguzismail the edit comment seems to have caused more confusion. jQuery is a library while JS is the language :P

Comment: @oguzismail it shouldn't really cause any confusion. It definitely wasn't confusing until now.

Comment: @Suraj Thanks. See VLAZ's comment below, apparently the editor has radical views on what is JS and what is not

Comment: It is a jQuery thing. The [script OP refers to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/5830517#5830517) returns a JavaScript object, not an HTML element. The functions css is a custom jQuery extend code not vanilla js. jQuery is more useful since the return value is not a regular html element instead a custom object. JavaScript solutions might not work.

Comment: @SagarV `$.extend` only merges two objects. That's it - nothing jQuery specific about it. Nowadays `Object.assign()` is equivalent to that call but it's always been possible. The only other jQuery calls are `.is()` which checks if an element matches a selector. At the time it was the most convenient way to do this check but we've had alternatives and a couple of years later `.matches()` was semi-officially added but again - it was possible anyway. The final usage of jQuery is `.attr()` which gets the value of an attribute. `.getAttribute()` was already available at the time.

Comment: @SagarV The code OP uses *happens* to use jQuery but the question has nothing to do with that - it's asking how to get a property off an object where the property name comes from the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object. That is part of the core browser API. There is nothing jQuery related in how the property name would be resolved.

Comment: "Please advise on how to settle this dispute." – I am not a native English speaker, so my lack of comprehension might be the problem here, but can anyone explain what the *actual* dispute is here? The question was edited, ~20m later, the OP posted a comment asking for clarification, about 40m later, the OP posted this question, and about 4m after that, the edit was rolled back. That doesn't seem much of a dispute to me.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the issue was the original edit and its edit comment which OP disagreed with and brought it to Meta. Once it got here it was rolled back by one of the participants here. As the answer says it could have been handled with a Mod flag also.

Answer (score 50):

Thanks for bringing this to the community's attention. However, it technically wasn't necessary - you could simply have raised a custom moderator flag on that question with the info you've provided (which is basically what I did), and one of the mods would have investigated, likely come to the same conclusion, and taken the appropriate actions. There really isn't a need to directly involve Meta in such cases, and indeed I would argue it's counterproductive as it can trigger witch-hunts and impede moderator rectification actions.

Moderators are busy people and stretched thin, and there are a lot of flags raised every day, and sometimes they don't get time to process all those flags, and sometimes they just miss things because they're fallible human beings. But if you aren't seeing the expected action on your flag within a day or so, or the flag is declined, then it's perfectly correct to escalate things by posting here. At the very least you'll likely get an explanation from the responsible moderator as to why the specific action was taken (or not).

---

I concur. The fact that the rev 3 edit comment `jquery is not javascript` is nonsense, also gives a clue that this is a bad edit. While the question is asked in a jQuery context, it is applicable to JavaScript as a whole - which is why the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag guidance explicitly suggests "consider also adding the JavaScript tag".

I've rolled that edit back. A mod should probably also ping this user [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606371/john) as they are making similar bad edits to multiple other questions - effectively, editing titles and retagging from [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) without community consensus. I've raised a custom mod flag on one of the questions this user has recently edited, linking back here for context, in case a mod doesn't see this anytime soon.

Edit: it gets worse - the same user has been retagging Angular and React questions too, because apparently those aren't JavaScript either... and this has been going on since at least March 2020.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I don't see anything at all in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7122609 that is specific to jQuery. To me this is a ***pure*** JavaScript question. The dispute is whether the question is *about JavaScript* or *about jQuery*? (The question certainly contains jQuery. That we can all agree on, I think.) . . . "Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*." - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/exception/info

Comment: >  you could simply have raised a custom moderator flag . . . . . OK. Point taken. I was uncertain what to do, so I did both actually. (I had already raised a moderator flag before writing this question/request, but maybe I should have waited 24 hours before bringing it up here?)

Comment: @Henke That's what I would have done. The mods are busy people and stretched thin, and there are a lot of flags raised every day, and sometimes they don't get time to process all those flags, and sometimes they just miss things because they're fallible human beings. But if you aren't seeing the expected action on your flag within a day or so, or the flag is declined, then it's perfectly correct to escalate things by posting to Meta.

Comment: There's also a lot of unnecessary fiddling with code by this editor - changing from camelCase to under_scores, for instance - which can result in code failing to run if this person is not careful enough. I'm sure there's a FAQ somewhere that says not to do this.